# codeigniter how to create tables for the models

Tags: codeigniter

I need to create the tables for the models i have in my code base with codeigniter,

is there a way to export the stuff to the codeignitor?

I have the codebase with me but i dont have a data dump, so I need to find a way to do something like the Rails migrations

Comment: have you looked at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html ??

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/libraries/migration.html - new website

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CodeIgniter's Migration and DBForge class

### Migrations

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html

### DBForge Database Manipulation

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html

**Straight From The UserGuide for migrations:**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Migration_Add_blog extends CI_Migration {

public function up()
{
    $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
        'blog_id' => array(
            'type' => 'INT',
            'constraint' => 5,
            'unsigned' => TRUE,
            'auto_increment' => TRUE
        ),
        'blog_title' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '100',
        ),
        'blog_description' => array(
            'type' => 'TEXT',
            'null' => TRUE,
        ),
    ));
    
    $this->dbforge->create_table('blog');
}

public function down()
{
    $this->dbforge->drop_table('blog');
}
```

Comment: i am looking for a way to migrate SQL to PHP, so you can create an initial migration for existing databases that can be used with an installer. I currently use an SQL file to create the base, and then any updates i push to my apps i simply run the migrations.